# Warning (Anachronism): Assigning void(*)(int) to extern "C" void(*)(int)

Tags: c++, function-pointers, solaris, linkage, sunstudio

I'm having trouble with Sun's C++ compiler. I've read Oracle's [Working with Pointers to Functions [from C++]](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mixingcandcpluspluscode-305840.html#pfn). Its a good read, and I get the impression SunCC is most compliant among all the compilers in this area (though its causing me trouble).

The test code is below, and line 24 is `new_handler.sa_handler = (pfn ? pfn : &SignalHandler::NullHandler);`. Unrolling the ternary operator shows this is the issue: `new_handler.sa_handler = pfn;`.

***SunCC 5.11***

```
$ /opt/solstudio12.2/bin/CC test.cxx
"test.cxx", line 24: Warning (Anachronism): Assigning void(*)(int) to extern "C" void(*)(int).
"test.cxx", line 58:     Where: While instantiating "SignalHandler<5, 0>::SignalHandler(void(*)(int), int)".
"test.cxx", line 58:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
```

***SunCC 5.12***

```
$ /opt/solarisstudio12.3/bin/CC test.cxx
"test.cxx", line 24: Warning (Anachronism): Assigning void(*)(int) to extern "C" void(*)(int).
"test.cxx", line 58:     Where: While instantiating "SignalHandler<5, 0>::SignalHandler(void(*)(int), int)".
"test.cxx", line 58:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
```

***SunCC 5.13***

```
$ /opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC test.cxx
"test.cxx", line 24: Warning (Anachronism): Using void(*)(int) to initialize extern "C" void(*)(int).
"test.cxx", line 58:     Where: While instantiating "SignalHandler<5, 0>::SignalHandler(void(*)(int), int)".
"test.cxx", line 58:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
```

***SunCC 5.14***

```
$ /opt/developerstudio12.5/bin/CC test.cxx
$
```

Its not exactly clear to me what the problem is. Here's a similar issue on the Oracle boards, but the OP is basically told to RTFM: [Sun Studio 11 "Warning (Anachronism)"](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1995585).

How do I resolve the anachronistic warning?

---

```
solaris:~$ cat test.cxx
#include <signal.h>

extern "C" {
  typedef void (*SignalHandlerFn) (int);
};

template <int S, bool O=false>
struct SignalHandler
{
  SignalHandler(SignalHandlerFn pfn = NULL, int flags = 0) : m_installed(false)
  {
    struct sigaction new_handler;

    do
    {
      int ret = 0;

      ret = sigaction (S, 0, &m_old);
      if (ret != 0) break; // Failed

      if (m_old.sa_handler != 0 && !O) break;

      new_handler.sa_handler = (pfn ? pfn : &SignalHandler::NullHandler);
      new_handler.sa_flags = (pfn ? flags : 0);

      ret = sigemptyset (&new_handler.sa_mask);
      if (ret != 0) break; // Failed

      ret = sigaction (S, &new_handler, 0);
      if (ret != 0) break; // Failed

      m_installed = true;

    } while(0);
  }

  ~SignalHandler()
  {
    if (m_installed)
      sigaction (S, &m_old, 0);
  }

private:
  struct sigaction m_old;
  bool m_installed;

  static void NullHandler(int /*unused*/) { /* continue*/ }

private:
  // Not copyable
  SignalHandler(const SignalHandler &);
  void operator=(const SignalHandler &);
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  SignalHandler<SIGTRAP, 0> handler;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the signature of NullHandler?

Comment: @kfsone - Its down towrds the bottom of the sample. The inline definition is `static void NullHandler(int /*unused*/) { }`. I also unrolled the ternary operator, and the problem is with `new_handler.sa_handler = pfn;`.

Comment: Shouldn't it also need to  be extern "C"?

Comment: @kfsone - one thing I've noticed... SunCC 12.3 and 12.4 have a habit of dropping qualifiers and the like. On two separate occasions, `const` was mysteriously omitted from signatures which resulted in failed links. We had to work around them [here](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/188) and [here](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/224).

Comment: @jww - maybe change SignalHandler::NullHandler to a regular C function would help? (Let's name it SignalHandler_NullHandler)
And both SignalHandler_NullHandler and SignalHandlerFn should be extern "C".

Comment: " I get the impression SunCC is most compliant among all the compilers" - Not at all. The standard grants some leeway to odd compilers such as SunCC, but using this freedom only makes it odd, not "more compliant".

Comment: @MSalters - Fair enough, but I look at it as a failure on our part to write portable code. I only know a portion of the standards (I think); I lack the (nearly complete) expert knowledge of folks like you. So I depend on the compiler to help improve the code.

Comment: @M.M - All the extraneous code and code comments have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

You may change SignalHandler::NullHandler to a regular C function (let's name it SignalHandler_NullHandler).
Then wrap both SignalHandler_NullHandler and SignalHandlerFn in extern „C”.

BTW. It was my guess how to „align” these two functions but you have explained it better in your comment that there is a problem with C/C++ casting.

Comment: @M.M - *"In standard C++ the C-style cast is defined as having the same effect as reinterpret_cast..."* - that's interesting because I am definitely seeing different behavior (C cast accepted, C++ cast not). The different behavior gave rise to the other question. The version that give trouble when using the `reinterpret_cast` on both sides of the ternary operator are SunCC 12.3 and 12.4.

Comment: I rolled back my edits because I went down the wrong path with the cast. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression:

```
pfn ? pfn : &SignalHandler::NullHandler
```

the second and third operands have different types (since one points to a function with "C" language linkage, and one points to a function with "C++" language linkage); and there is no implicit conversion that changes the language linkage.

So that expression is ill-formed.   Another answer suggests using casts, however that may suppress a diagnostic at the expense of silent undefined behaviour at runtime: calling a function through a pointer to function of different type.

It's possible that particular compilers provide extensions to define behaviour in any scenario that is undefined by the C++ Standard, of course. (Or happen to "work anyway").

My recommendation would be to replace `SignalHandler::NullHandler` with a function that has C language linkage. This can't be a class member because the language grammar precludes `extern "C"` from appearing inside a class definition.