# Does a C++ cast strip the 'extern "C"' from a declaration?

Tags: c++, linkage, reinterpret-cast

This question is related to [Warning (Anachronism): Assigning `void(*)(int)` to `extern "C" void(*)(int)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39562034). In the cited question, we had a function pointer typedef declared as `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" {
  typedef void (*SignalHandlerFn) (int);
};
```

When we attempted to assign it:

```
new_handler.sa_handler = (pfn ? reinterpret_cast<SignalHandlerFn>(pfn) :
                                reinterpret_cast<SignalHandlerFn>(defaultHandler));
```

It resulted in the error (the line numbers are a bit off, but the line above produces it):

```
/opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC -DDEBUG -c test.cpp
...
"ossig.h", line 75: Warning (Anachronism): Using void(*)(int) to initialize extern "C" void(*)(int).
"test.cpp", line 135:     Where: While instantiating "SignalHandler<5, 0>::SignalHandler(extern "C" void(*)(int), int)".
"test.cpp", line 135:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
2 Warning(s) detected.
```

The best I can tell, the `extern "C"` was discarded when using the `reinterpret_cast`. However, a C cast worked as expected.

I believe Sun Studio 12.4 (SunCC 5.13) uses C++03 by defult. But my question applies to both C++03 and C++11 since we see a lot of both at the moment due to the popularity of GCC 4.8 and 4.9.

Does a C++ cast strip the `extern "C"` from a declaration?

---

```
solaris:~$ cat test.cxx
#include <signal.h>

extern "C" {
  typedef void (*SignalHandlerFn) (int);
};

template <int S, bool O=false>
struct SignalHandler
{
  SignalHandler(SignalHandlerFn pfn = NULL, int flags = 0) : m_installed(false)
  {
    struct sigaction new_handler;

    do
    {
      int ret = 0;

      ret = sigaction (S, 0, &m_old);
      if (ret != 0) break; // Failed

      if (m_old.sa_handler != 0 && !O) break;

      new_handler.sa_handler = (pfn ? reinterpret_cast<SignalHandlerFn>(pfn) :
                                      reinterpret_cast<SignalHandlerFn>(&SignalHandler::NullHandler));
      new_handler.sa_flags = (pfn ? flags : 0);

      ret = sigemptyset (&new_handler.sa_mask);
      if (ret != 0) break; // Failed

      ret = sigaction (S, &new_handler, 0);
      if (ret != 0) break; // Failed

      m_installed = true;

    } while(0);
  }

  ~SignalHandler()
  {
    if (m_installed)
      sigaction (S, &m_old, 0);
  }

private:
  struct sigaction m_old;
  bool m_installed;

  static void NullHandler(int /*unused*/) { /* continue*/ }

private:
  // Not copyable
  SignalHandler(const SignalHandler &);
  void operator=(const SignalHandler &);
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  SignalHandler<SIGTRAP, 0> handler;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Language linkage is part of the type of a function (and you can overload on it); unfortunately, most compilers don't implement this correctly.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek. Does that mean SunCC is correct, my `SignalHandlerFn` is wrong and other compilers should be rejecting it? Or does that mean SunCC is mishandling it? Sorry to ask. I know how to work around it; but I'm still not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Your `NullHandler` is definitely wrong, since class member functions never have C linkage. Indeed, GCC and Clang ignore this completely. You can double-check with Embarcadero, which I believe implements these rules correctly. On the other hand, `pfn` should be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `reinterpret_cast<T>` either produces an expression of type `T`, or is ill-formed due to no allowable conversion existing.   (ref: [expr.reinterpret.cast]/1).

The language linkage is part of the type (ref: [dcl.link]/1).

So the result of `reinterpret_cast<SignalHandlerFn>` is either ill-formed, or a pointer to function with C language linkage.

Accordingly, it doesn't seem correct to describe this cast as "stripping extern C" -- although of course a compiler may react to ill-formed code by issuing a diagnostic, and then proceeding as if the code had some arbitrary behaviour.

---

In your code sample, both uses of `reinterpret_cast<SignalHandlerFn>` are well-formed , because `reinterpret_cast` may convert any function pointer to any other function pointer (ref: [expr.reinterpret.cast]/6).

However, calling `SignalHandler::NullHandler` through `sa_handler` will cause undefined behaviour (ref: ibid.).  The warning produced by your compiler could be intended to warn about this case.

Comment: I will remark though: it seems a common compiler behaviour to allow implicit conversion from "extern C++" functions, to "extern C" function pointers.   Maybe this is done on purpose for practical reasons by the compiler vendors

Comment: Because it's not sane for it to be part of the type. In fact I've never seen a case where it actually made a difference. Now you can't pass a class member function to C but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

The sigaction structure is defined as:

```
   struct sigaction {
       void     (*sa_handler)(int);
       void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
       sigset_t   sa_mask;
       int        sa_flags;
       void     (*sa_restorer)(void);
   };
```

And you use struct sigaction's  void     (*sa_handler)(int); to get assigned from some SignalHandlerFn.
So, either both declarations should be within `extern "C"` e.g.

```
extern "C" {
  #include <signal.h>
};
```

and

```
extern "C" {
  typedef void (*SignalHandlerFn) (int);
};
```

Or both should be with support of C++'s name mangling, i.ee. without `extern "C"` as:

```
  #include <signal.h>
```

and

```
  typedef void (*SignalHandlerFn) (int);
```

Comment: `signal.h` is a header file for functions from the C standard library, the declarations need `extern "C"` linkage (usually the header file will detect C++ and set the linkage correctly, it is unnecessary to do `extern "C" { #include`)

Comment: Just an FYI... The Solaris docs at [Working with Pointers to Functions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mixingcandcpluspluscode-305840.html#pfn) specifically state we should not include with an `extern "C"`.

Comment: Standard headers should already include `extern "C"` where applicable, it is undefined behaviour to write what you did